# Performing an openquery that includes a date variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am unable to include a date variable in my OpenQuery on SQL Server Management Studio. I wish to have a dynamic date that is updated for each iteration of a stored procedure (so I can run multiple months).  The query I am attempting to run is:

```
Declare @Counter int = 1
Declare @DateInt int = (select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(M, @Counter-1, @StartInfoDate), 112) AS [YYYYMMDD])



Select * from 
OpenQuery(MyOracle,'Select
    * FROM DERIVED.ACCOUNT_TABLE@READONLY.DW.UAT.IM T
    where 
    Rownum <= 10 and 
    T.INFORMATION_DATE = to_date(''' + convert(Varchar(8), @DateInt) +  ''', ''dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'')
```

I expect to get results but I keep getting:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Incorrect syntax near '+'.
>
> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '', 'dd-mon-yyyy >hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: You're converting a date to a string then an int then back to a *localized* string, then convert that back to a date on Oracle's side. Create a string with the format you want just once and use [date or timestamp literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) in the query

Comment: To get a date as a string in the YYYY-MM-DD format, use `format(getdate(),'yyyy-MM-dd')`. The result can be used as a DATE literal in Oracle, ie `DATE '2019-05-31'`. You could put everything in a single line, eg `INFORMATION_DATE = DATE ''' + format(getdate(),'yyyy-MM-dd') + ''''` although it's better to store the string in a separate variable to keep the query clean. In fact, it would be a good idea to construct the query string in a separate line. This would make it easier to inspect it and avoid missing parentheses or quotes

Comment: If you simply printed your concatenated string you'd see the issue straight away. BUt yes I agree with other posters - this can be done in a much simpler fashion